# preg_match character class replacing too much

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a little problem with regex. I want to clean up a string.

Currently I'm using the following regex:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]/", "", "Example1:2@32");
```

which gives me: "Example1232"

But the colon shouldn't be replaced, too. I tried it already with:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-:]/", "", "Example1:2@32");
```

but that doesn't work. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape `-` character

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 _\-:]/", "", "Example1:2@32"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I totaly missed it. I just looked at the colon and thought this was the problem...

Answer (score 2):

Either method should work:

- escape the dash `-` or
- put the dash `-` at the end of your regex, since inbetween two other characters it has a certain meaning (namely a range, as in `a-z`).